# AttributeError: module 'dill' has no attribute 'extend'

Tags: python, pytorch, attributeerror, dill

I have just installed Pytorch, using:

```
(base) C:\>pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio
Requirement already satisfied: torch in c:\users\Emil\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (1.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: torchvision in c:\users\Emil\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: torchaudio in c:\users\Emil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.12.1)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in c:\users\Emil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from torch) (3.7.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\Emil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from torchvision) (1.22.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=5.3.0 in c:\users\Emil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from torchvision) (8.0.1)
```

Then, I tried to import torch in Spyder but received the following error:

```
import torch
C:\Users\Emil\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\torch\package\_mock_zipreader.py:17: UserWarning: Failed to initialize NumPy: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import (Triggered internally at  ..\torch\csrc\utils\tensor_numpy.cpp:67.)
  _dtype_to_storage = {data_type(0).dtype: data_type for data_type in _storages}
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-eb42ca6e4af3>", line 1, in <module>
    import torch

  File "C:\Users\Emil\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 705, in <module>
    import torch.utils.data

  File "C:\Users\Emil\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\torch\utils\data\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from torch.utils.data import datapipes

  File "C:\Users\Emil\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\torch\utils\data\datapipes\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import iter

  File "C:\Users\Emil\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\torch\utils\data\datapipes\iter\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from torch.utils.data.datapipes.iter.callable import \

  File "C:\Users\Emil\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\torch\utils\data\datapipes\iter\callable.py", line 13, in <module>
    dill.extend(use_dill=False)

AttributeError: module 'dill' has no attribute 'extend'
```

What can I do to overcome this error?

Comment: I'm the `dill` author. The `dill` module does provide an `extend` attribute. I noticed that `dill` doesn't show up in the requirements, however... so, it might be possible that you have a really really really old version of `dill` installed.  I would think more likely that there's an import error somewhere that overwrites the `dill` module. It may be worthwhile to report as a potential `pytorch` bug on GitHub if you haven't already.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Mike McKerns' comment, I successfully used:

```
pip install dill --upgrade
```